# How to reset the Border color of a text box to the default system color

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm changing the color of a textbox to red for validation in WPF

I can't find a way to change it back to the system default upon clearing my form.

I thought there was an easy way to change it back to the default by clearing the border brush proper but I can't seem to find it.

Is there an easy way to reset it to the default with out having to set it manually to the system color?

Comment: BorderBrush is how I am changing it, so I would need to reset that property.

Answer (score 6):

Found out how to do it:

```
Textbox.ClearValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty)
```

Comment: @CalvinSmith, You don't know he didn't google it first.  It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions, and it's helpful to the community at large if someone else has the same problem.  +1 for Tbooty

Comment: @KyleMit Im questioning the post, and answering yourself 7 minutes later.

Comment: @CalvinSmith, yeah, I understood that.  I'm just saying doing exactly that is awesome sauce.  We want people continuing to search and answer their own questions at any point in time.  You might disagree, but I think it's one of the things that makes this community and it's users great.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox.BorderColor = Color.Empty
```